# I am trying to use the address selected on the google places screen to draw a route on the map when an address is selected and screen closes

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I am cloning an uber like app and need to use the address selected by the user on the google places screen to my function that draws the route,it keeps saying the data received from google places is not a string and cannot find location when i pass it to my send request function that finally draws the route on the map, am i missing something, i thought the value selected by the user was a string or is it an integer, forgive my ignorance im a bit new to this

this the code that takes the user to the google places screen using an ontap action

```
Positioned(
                  top: 105.0,
                  right: 30.0, 
                  left: 40.0,
                  child: Container(
                    height: 55,
                    width: 70.0,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(3.0),
                      color: Colors.white,
                      boxShadow: [
                        BoxShadow(
                            color: Colors.grey,
                            offset: Offset(1.0, 5.0),
                            blurRadius: 4,
                            spreadRadius: 1)
                      ],
                    ),
                    child: TextField(onTap: () async{
     Prediction p = await PlacesAutocomplete.show(
                context: context, apiKey: kGoogleApiKey);
                            displayRoute(p);

  },
                      cursorColor: Colors.black,
                       controller: appState.destinationController,
                     
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        icon: Container(
                          margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, top: 0,bottom: 6),
                          width: 10,
                          height: 10,
                          child: Icon(
                            Icons.local_taxi,
                            color: Colors.black,
                          ),
                        ),
                        hintText: "Where to?",
                        border: InputBorder.none,
                        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 15.0, top: 10.0),
                      ), 
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
```

this is the display route function that receives the data from google places screen

```
Future<Null> displayRoute(Prediction p) async {
    if (p != null) {
      

 appState.sendRequest(t);
    }
  }
```

And this is the code that takes that data from the google places screen to the send request that draws on the map

```
  // ! SEND REQUEST
  void sendRequest(String intendedLocation) async {
    List<Placemark> placemark =
        await Geolocator().placemarkFromAddress(intendedLocation);
    double latitude = placemark[0].position.latitude;
    double longitude = placemark[0].position.longitude;
    LatLng destination = LatLng(latitude, longitude);
    _addMarker(destination, intendedLocation);
    String route = await _googleMapsServices.getRouteCoordinates(
        _initialPosition, destination);
    createRoute(route);
    notifyListeners();
  }
```

Error Log:

```
Exception has occurred. PlatformException (PlatformException(ERROR_GEOCODNG_ADDRESSNOTFOUND, Unable to find coordinates matching the supplied address., null))
```

Comment: please paste any error log you are getting

Comment: ok sure, i get this error

Comment: Exception has occurred.
PlatformException (PlatformException(ERROR_GEOCODNG_ADDRESSNOTFOUND, Unable to find coordinates matching the supplied address., null))